# rxjs debounce and interval

Tags: javascript, rxjs, debouncing

There are lots of information and questions about **RXJS debounce** method.
But I cannot understand why this most simple example doesn't work:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .debounce(() => Rx.Observable.interval(2500))
  .subscribe(result  => console.log(result, '!'));
```

**Interval** emits incremental number every 1 second (assume `----` is one second)

```
---1---2---3---4---5
---------d---------d
```

In this case I expected to see `2 and 5` numbers, but it shows **nothing**.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debounce` waits until no emissions are done for *x* time and then emits the last value

```
-a-b-b-c----a---
----------c----a
```

If you want to have only one value for every *x* time units then you can look at `buffer` or `window` operators